# Which Django asset manager/compressor is Python 3 compatible?

Tags: django, python-3.x, less

I finally want to migrate a Django project to Python 3.3 but have some issues with django-compressor, because it is not Python 3 compatible (yet).

Out of the asset managers listed on https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/ these seem interesting to me, since they support CSS/LESS too:

- https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/webassets/
- https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-pipeline/
- https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-gears/

I have multiple CSS and LESS files, and a lot of JavaScript files which need to be minified, and Python 3.3 must be supported. What would you recommend for my use case? Are there other, better suited projects around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use a django-pipeline.  It supports python 3 and do what it should do. I used it for one of my project ( but it was python 2.7) and perfectly happy with it.